# clojure.string/replace does not match pattern matched by re-seq

Tags: regex, clojure

Why does `clojure.string/replace` not match the `\"[^\"]+\"` pattern while `re-seq` does?

```
(re-seq #"\"[^\"]+\"" "ab,\"helo,bro\",yo")
=> ("\"helo,bro\"")       

(clojure.string/replace "ab,\"helo,bro\",yo" #"\"[^\"]+\”" "") 
=> "ab,\"helo,bro\",yo"
```

I would expect `replace` to delete the matched pattern. What am I missing here?

Thanks for insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex are (probably unintentionally) different: in the `replace` option you used `\”` instead of `\"`.

If you use the same exact regex it will work as expected:

```
(def r #"\"[^\"]+\"")

(re-seq r "ab,\"helo,bro\",yo")
=> ("\"helo,bro\"")

(clojure.string/replace "ab,\"helo,bro\",yo" r "") 
=> "ab,,yo"
```